# redrawing on ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to redraw the content of a simple loop. So far it prints out to the `stdscr` 100 lines, and then by using `scrl` to scroll n lines I get n blank rows.

What I want is to keep with the sequence. However, I'm not sure how to redraw the `stdscr` with the n extra lines. Any ideas will be appreciate it!

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    int maxy,maxx,y;
    getmaxyx(stdscr,maxy,maxx);
    scrollok(stdscr,TRUE);
    for(y=0;y<=100;y++)
        mvprintw(y,0,"This is some text written to line %d.",y);
    refresh();
    getch();
    scrl(5);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, after the `refresh()` after `scrl()`, add the lines:

```
for (y = 96; y <= 100; y++)
    mvprintw(y, 0, "This is some text written as line %d.", y+5);
refresh();
```

I'm using magic numbers, of course.  You should use something like:

```
enum { MAX_SCR_LINE = 100 };
enum { MAX_SCROLL   =   5 };
```

Then the loop is:

```
for (y = MAX_SCR_LINE - MAX_SCROLL + 1; y <= MAX_SCR_LINE; y++)
    mvprintw(y, 0, "This is some text written as line %d.", y + MAX_SCROLL);
refresh();
```

And if you need to repeat the process over, and over, then the calculation becomes:

```
enum { MAX_ITER = 10 };
for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ITER; j++)
{
    scrl(MAX_SCROLL);
    for (y = MAX_SCR_LINE - MAX_SCROLL + 1; y <= MAX_SCR_LINE; y++)
        mvprintw(y, 0, "This is the text written as line %d.",
                 y + (j + 1) * MAX_SCROLL);
 }
```

Etcetera...

(Code untested - beware bugs.)